# C# PowerShell ApartmentState = STA not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to import a module in PowerShell which need -STA option, I set the Runspace.ApartmentState to STA but when I import the module its fail on missing the -STA option, I tried to use module "StarWindX" but I do not think it is module dependent problem, here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        iss.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;

        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss)) {
            Console.WriteLine("ApartmentState: " + ps.Runspace.ApartmentState.ToString());
            ps.AddScript(
                "Import-Module StarWindX"
                );

            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();
            if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error) {
                    Console.WriteLine("ps error: " + error.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("ps error: " + error.ScriptStackTrace);
                }
            }
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput) {
                if (outputItem != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine("ps: " + outputItem.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

which output is:

ApartmentState: STA

ps error: StarWindX doesn't support current appartment. You need to run this script with -STA switch to use StarWindX.

ps error: at , C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\StarWindX\StarWindX.psm1: line 4 at ScriptBlock, No file: line 1

Here is the first 4 line of the .psm1 file:

```
if ($host.Runspace.ApartmentState -ne 'STA') 
{
    #write-host "You need to run this script with -STA switch or inside ISE"
    throw "StarWindX doesn't support current appartment. You need to run this script with -STA switch to use StarWindX."
}
```

How can I set the ApartmentSate correctly?

Comment: You can try `ps.AddScript("Import-Module StarWindX").AddParameter("STA");`, or with just `ps.AddScript("Import-Module StarWindX -STA");`

Comment: @Hackerman I tried, unfortunately, it did not help